# Scalable REST API using SPRING MVC

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, jmeter

How to consistently increment a number `(i.e a table in MySQL with one integer field)` in a database when parallel threads are racing to increment the number?

(Need to create **SCALABLE** RESTFUL API using Spring MVC. Also,make use of Jmeter.)

Comment: `update table foo set counter = counter + 1 where ...`?

Comment: This is way too broad. Read the documentation of Spring MVC. We won't write a whole tutorial here. The documentation, tutorials and examples of Spring MVC exist for a reason.

Comment: Yes,I understand that part but  I need code snippet for how to make API scalable using JMeter?

Comment: That makes no sense. There isn't a magical flag that would transform non-scaleable code into scaleable code. And if it existed, it would be turned on by default, don't you think? And you don't make something scallable using JMeter. JMeter is a tool used to measure performance. It can be used, along with careful analysis to try detecting performance problems, compare various solutions in terms of performance, etc. Your question sounds like someone who have juste learned assembling lego bricks, and asking "please show me how to create a 100-floors skyscraper which resists to earthquakes".